# PHP boolean in class being a fatal error

Tags: php, class, boolean

I was working with php Booleans in a class when I noticed everytime I tried to make one I got an error here is a smaller version of my code

```
class my_class
{

  public $hide_image == true;

}
```

thats the part of my code thats failing, without that boolean it works fine, but nothing on the page will show up when its there. How can I fix this? I am doing something wrong?

Comment: use only 1 equal `=` to assign a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake that you using comparison operator "==" instead of "=". As a result your public property looks like that:

```
class my_class
{
    public true;

}
```

Right:

```
class my_class
{
    public $hide_image = true;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`==` compares the values of variables for equality. `=` sets.

```
public $hide_image = true;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

You are using double ==.

you should only use 1 = to assign a value

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class my_class
{
    public $hide_image = true;
}
```